# Correct legal way of abroad income to indian savings account

Tags: taxes, india, international-transfer

In have been abroad for nearly four months and earning abroad in SGD. Now I would be returning back to india. My duration of abroad stay is less then 182 days. I want to transfer my earnings back to india now in legal way. Can I just remit it directly to my savings account in India?

Comment: But I might have to pay tax on the earnings here in Singapore aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can transfer to your savings account.

Note as you have spent more than 182 days in India, you will be classified as resident Indian. All your income will be taxable in India.